# Prestashop 1.7.1.1: Create a valid token for AJAX calls and validate it

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I´m trying to create a secure ajax call on prestaphop 1.7.1.1 [following this instrucctions.](http://build.prestashop.com/howtos/module/Common-mistakes-while-coding-module/)

```
<?php
// In your form use:
<input type="hidden" value="{Token::getToken()}">

// In your module controller, in postProcess (or some other methods who is made for data validation) check:

if (!$this->isTokenValid()) {
    // Ooops! Token is not valid!
    die('Token is not valid, hack stop');
```

But `{Token::getToken()}` doesn't exists. I´m creating a new admin module, not a front module.

How I can create a token and check it on prestashop 1.7.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the class `Token` has never existed (from what I remember)...

Try this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules')} name="token">
```

Then retrieve it in your ajax call (I'm supposing your code):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : {
        token : $('#yourform').find('input[name="token"]').val()
    },
    ...
});
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: How can validate the token??

Comment: In your admin controller you have to do a simple if, e.g. `if(Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules')==Tools::getValue('token'))`